# IBM Maximo - empty Reported Date required field on the Service Request application

Tags: maximo

When I create a new record on the Service Request (SR) application (Maximo 7.6), I would like to set the required Reported Date (SR.REPORTDATE) field blank. Before save action, the user will input data into that field. I wonder how this could be done?

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look in Database Configuration to see if REPORTDATE has a Default Value, I think you'll find &SYSDATE& in there. If I'm right, then you can delete that default value, save your changes, and apply your changes. Otherwise, you'll need to do as @Dex suggested.

Answer (score 0):

My mind immediately goes to an automation script. A default value control or the default value setting in Database Configuration may work too and is recommended before a script if you have the expertise to confirm or deny this theory.

As for the automation script, I think you can create one with an object launch point on SR on the "add" event. The script would simply set that field to null, which shouldn't change the "required" flag either, so the rest of your needs will still be met.

```
mbo.setValueNull("REPORTDATE");
```

Comment: The problem with this automation script idea is that putting it on the Add launch point happens when the user hits `Save`, not when they hit `New`. You would be better to put it on `Initialize` and only do the `setValueNull()` if `mbo.toBeAdded()`. The check for `toBeAdded()` is necessary to avoid blanking out the Reported Date for records coming back on the List tab.

Comment: That said, checking `toBeAdded()` is substandard, too. You'd really rather have an Object Event Condition (OEC) that prevents your launch point / script from being invoked unless it has something to do, to save set-up/tear-down performance expenses. For SR, that OEC might be `not exists (select 1 from ticket where ticketuid = :ticketuid)`.

Comment: Yep. This answer does appear flawed; I'm pretty sure I did mean on the "save" event but the "add" filter of that (though my next comment explains more). Initialize scripts are annoying because they run _so often_, but sometimes with autoscripts that's all you have. Initialize also runs pretty early, before some of the setup of the MBO, so it may not always have the data available that you need available (or even have the fields you need to reference initialized). I wonder how cheap those SQL conditions are to run each time either, but I'm hopefully over-optimizing at this point.

Comment: There is the special ".NEW" autoscript trigger in some (all?) versions of 7.6.0.x that causes the script to launch only when a record is created. You have to name the script after the object name and add that suffix, so the script name in this case would be "SR.NEW". This would be the real "add" event I wanted when I wrote this a year ago. I think I heard that they added proper support for this in 7.6.1.x.